# How to swap prototype for jquery in rails 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to swap prototype for jquery in rails 3.0?

Answer (score 4):

Add to your Gemfile and `bundle install`

```
gem "jquery-rails"
```

Run the generator:

```
rails generate jquery:install
```

See the [github page](http://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery with Rails 3](http://joshhuckabee.com/jquery-rails-3).

Google is your friend.